# Intellij autobuild - non existent

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I remove a method, the error (elsewhere in code due to no method existing) is not displayed until I manually build project. There is no way to get this to autobuild on save/change ?

Is there an option I am missing somewhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try [IDEA 12 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP), it supports background compilation. See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/brand-new-compiler-mode-in-intellij-idea-12-leda/ for more details.

Comment: File > Default Settings > Compiler > Make project automatically

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, the [Eclipse Mode plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3822). It lets you always compile in the background, like Eclipse does. Works like a charm.

Apart from that: in IntelliJ, don't just delete a method manually, use `Refactor > Safe Delete ...`. It will walk you through all places in your code where the method is used. That's the IntelliJ way to do it.

Comment: Plugins.PLUGINS! I was sick of plugins thats why I am leaving eclipse.  Is there a good reason not to have this as default behaviour or at least a standanrd option ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky read the second part of my answer. IntelliJ supports a different way of thinking, everything is about refactoring. Use the refactoring tools, don't just edit code manually.

Comment: I have also left Eclipse about a month ago, and it takes me time to get used to IntelliJ, but whenever I think I found a bug, the bug is actually in my head ;-)

Comment: I can refactor in eclipse/netbeans, autobuild has other benefits, doesn't it ? The fact its being included in new release, suggests its an oversight rather than an attempt to promote best practice in some way. Netbeans is winning so far in my evaluation.

Comment: I don't know NetBeans, but Refactoring in IntelliJ is far superior to that in Eclipse. In Eclipse, as you say, you *can* refactor. In IntelliJ, it is the only proper way, you *must* refactor to get the full value of the IDE. In my opinion, IntelliJ is far superior to any other IDE I have known so far, but you have to use it the way it was intended.

Comment: @NimChimpsky For example: Have you tried [Structural Search and Replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html)? Search / Replace on the AST. I am not aware of any other tool that can do that.

Comment: that was quick ok thanks, I was about to dive in have a look myself.