# Classes do not change

Tags: java, gradle, build, compilation, .class-file

I have faced with a strange problem. Once I change the `.java` file - it seems that tests are using still the previous version of that file (`.class`).

From my point of view the class should be removed from `.build` folder and be recompiled from the new version of the .java file, but this only happens when I manually start build from Gradle.

Can I somehow turn on the autorebuild solution for `.java` files on change? 
Or can I do this event without gradle? I'm using Intellij Idea.

Comment: Probably.  Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Maybe your IDE is not configured to initiate the gradle build. Is it an IDE? Is it IntelliJ / Eclipse?

Comment: How are we supposed to know how you configured your gradle; and in what way you are doing your builds?

Comment: Im using Intellij Idea guys.

Comment: Then you may find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12744303/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11878189/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14635602/).

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to invalidate cache . in intellij idea "File/Invalidate Caches"

Comment: can you try deleting .class file?

Comment: I deleted .class, recompiled the .java file into new .class, and I see that new version of .java is in there, in the build directory, but somehow tests are still using the OLD one, wtf is this?

Comment: You deleted test class file as well?

Comment: Yes, I Deleted class files as well.